# How to clear VS code source control list after installing dependencies?

Tags: javascript, git, github, visual-studio-code, editor

I cloned my own nodeJS app in my vs code and then I used the command line to install dependencies. everythings works fine but the problem is my source control section where you stage and commit changed has 2000+ files in a list. is there a way to clear it without deleting files? [this is a screenshot of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzVr0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `.gitignore`  file which will do as its name suggests, ignore specified folders and files.

1. Create a .gitignore file in your root directory
2. inside it write `node_modules` so that the node_modules folder isn't tracked.
3. node_modules shouldn't be visible anymore

More about [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: glad I could help, don't forget to mark your question as answered if it is resolved, thanks

Comment: Didn't know that I could, I'm new here. will surely do! I tried to upvote but they wouldn't allow it because I don't have enough points yet

Answer (score 0):

Just Delete the **.git** folder from the root directory. Make sure you check the View All Files and Folder Option in windows explorer first